# Property Does Not Get Injected Via Autofac

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I Have An IDbContext Interface In Another Assembly And A Service Stack In Another Assembly , The Base Service Class has a Property Of IDbContext and other Services Do Use Its Property.

To Make Matters Simple I Omit The Base Service Class And even in this Scenario it does not work.
here is IDbContext :

```
public interface IDbContext
{   
}
```

Then I Have a DBContext Class Which Implements IDbContext.
In Another Assembly We Have This Class Which has A IDContext Property :

```
public class StudyFieldService : IStudyFieldService{
    private readonly IDbSet<StudyField> _studyFields;
    public IDbContext DbContext { get; set; }
    public StudyFieldService(IDbContext db)
    {
        _studyFields = DbContext.Set<StudyField>();
    }
}
```

Then I have Autofac Registry Class Which Maps Classes To Interfaces and the Registry Class Is Also in Another Assembly 
This Is The Body Of The Method Which maps the types :

```
 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<SalaryDbContext>().As<IDbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<StudyFieldService>().As<IStudyFieldService>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

Now if I Put The IDbContext In The Constructor Param Autofac Resolves it but I Want it to be injected as a property and Automatically.

Comment: Do you get an exception? Or is value of the property `null`?

Comment: Value of the property is null

Comment: I just tested it and it works properly. Did you miss something to provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon you should remove the constructor injection and change the DbContext variable name to something else or use this.DbContext to make it work.

```
public class StudyFieldService : IStudyFieldService{
    private readonly IDbSet<StudyField> _studyFields;
    public IDbContext Context{ get; set; }
    public StudyFieldService()
    {
        _studyFields = Context.Set<StudyField>();
    }
}
```

I guess there is a conflict on variable name with ef DbContext